# How to track Facebook comments with Google Analytics' social tracking

Tags: google-analytics, facebook-comments

I've been looking for an up-to-date walkthrough of including Facebook's comments plugin in GA's social tracking system. There are a few tutorials available but all are dated and don't seem to work. Does anyone here have any suggestions?

Specifically, I'm trying to get the GA asynchronous tracker (ga.js) to report comments left with Facebook's XFBML version of the comments plugin. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's what I've done so far, though it doesn't appear to work:

1. Added this to the ga_social_tracking.js provided by Google:

> ```
>  FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(opt_target) {
>     _gaq.push(_ga.getSocialActionTrackers_('Facebook', 'Comment',
>         opt_target, opt_pagePath));
>   });
>   FB.Event.subscribe('comment.remove', function(opt_target) {
>     _gaq.push(_ga.getSocialActionTrackers_('Facebook', 'Uncomment',
>         opt_target, opt_pagePath));
>   });
> ```

1. Added xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" to the document's opening .
2. Linked to that document in the page :

> ```
> <script src="/includes/ga_social_tracking.js"></script>
> ```

1. Have installed the Facebook JavaScript SDK immediately after

> ```
> <div id="fb-root"></div>
> <script>
> (function(d, s, id) {
> var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
> if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
> js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
> js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=<MYAPPID>";
> fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
> }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')
> );
> </script>
> ```

1. Called the Facebook comments plugin via the XFBML method, adding _ga.trackFacebook and notify="true":

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">_ga.trackFacebook();</script><fb:comments href="http://example.com" width="450" num_posts="10" notify="true"></fb:comments>
> ```

Clearly I've done something wrong here as comments are not tracking in GA's Traffic Sources/Social/Plugins reports, though Facebook Like/unlike, Twitter and even LinkedIn (after customization) are working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.